# Is there a way to call function right after the selector is removed - jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="section">
  <div class="count">2 <button class="click">Click</button><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>
  <div class="count">3 <button class="click">Click</button><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>
  <div class="count">4 <button class="click">Click</button><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>
</div>
<div class="section">
  <div class="count">2 <button class="click">Click</button><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>
  <div class="count">3 <button class="click">Click</button><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>
  <div class="count">4 <button class="click">Click</button><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>
</div>
```

This function counter() is for multiple purpose so I prefer to keep without modification

```
$.fn.counter = function() {
  var counter = 1;
  $(this).closest('.section').find('.count').each(function(){
    $(this).text(counter);
    counter++;
  })
};
```

This function update count

```
$('body').on('click', '.click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.count').addClass('active').counter();
});
```

This function doesn't update count since element is removed

So is there a way to call function counter() right after element is removed? I need to update the remaining count which are not removed inside section.

```
$('body').on('click', '.delete', function(){
    var self = $(this).closest('.count');
    $(this).closest('.count').remove().counter();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/michaelyuen/duopttkk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there are 2 flaws in your plugin logic (`$.fn.counter`). `this`, in your function is already a jQuery object, so no needs to do `$(this).closest(...)`, simply do `this.closest(...)`.

Also, you should return `this` at the end of the function. That will allow to chain methods and partly solve your problem. So your plugin should look like this:

```
$.fn.counter = function() {
  var counter = 1;
  this.closest('.section').find('.count').each(function(){
    $(this).text(counter);
    counter++;
  });
  return this;
};
```

After making those changes, just invert the `.counter` function and the `.remove`:

```
$(this).closest('.count').counter().remove();
```

---

After understanding that you to consider the current element outside of the counter, your function has to change a bit. Without those changes, it won't be possible to achieve what you want since when you remove the `.count`, it is no longer inside a `div.section` so `closest` return an empty object.

You need to add an argument to your plugin. That argument will default to a `falsy` value, so it will not affect your other function calls.

```
$.fn.counter = function( ignore_self ) {
  var counter = 1;
  var $counters = this.closest('.section').find('.count');
  if( ignore_self ) $counters = $counters.not(this);

  $counters.each(function(){
    $(this).text(counter);
    counter++;
  });
  return this;
};
```

Then, when calling `counter` before removing the element, pass true:

```
$(this).closest('.count').counter(true).remove();
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/duopttkk/4/

Comment: Thanks for correction. But if I invert the .counter and .remove, .counter will fire first and this will count the removed element as well. https://jsfiddle.net/michaelyuen/duopttkk/3/

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen Are you willing to pass an additional argument to your function? I doubt it is doable without it: https://jsfiddle.net/duopttkk/4/

Comment: your reference is really helpful eventhough I am still reluctant to make changes to all other scripts that call the same .counter(). I was thinking how to make reference to the selector before it's removed. So I guess not.

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen Actually, the change I made to your code won't affect the other places where you call `.counter()` since by default, `ignore_self` is false. Your code will act as it used before. You'll only need to add `true` when removing the element. The problem is that since you remove the element, it is no longer inside `.section`, so `closest` return an empty object.

Comment: yes, I made my response too quickly without digesting it fully. Can you update your answer so I can accept that, please?

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen Done, let me know if something's not clear!

Answer (score 1):

> This function counter() is for multiple purpose so I prefer to keep without modification

If, instead, you can change such a function here is my proposal.

Your issue is in this line:

```
$(this).text(counter);
```

Your inner elements elements are:

```
<div class="count">2 <button class="click">
............................
```

Hence, if you want to change the number 2 to another value you need to get that node. Such a node is a text node and you can get it filtering by node type (you cannot use text method):

```
$(ele).contents().filter(function(idx, ele) {
      return ele.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
}).first().get(0).textContent = counter;
```

From your comment:

> It is in fact a <span> inside .

In this way you can simplify your counter to:

```
$.fn.counter = function() {
    $(this).closest('.section').find('.count span').each(function(idx, ele){
        $(ele).text(idx + 1);
    })
};
```

```js
// this function counter is for multiple purpose so I prefer not to keep without modification
$.fn.counter = function() {
    $(this).closest('.section').find('.count span').each(function(idx, ele){
        $(ele).text(idx + 1);
    })
};


// this function update count

$('body').on('click', '.click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.count').addClass('active').counter();
});

// this function doesn't update count since element is removed
// Is there a way to fire function after event target is removed

$('body').on('click', '.delete', function(){
    var self = $(this).closest('.count');
    $(this).closest('.count').remove().counter();
});
```

```css
.active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="section">
    <div class="count"><span>2</span><button class="click">Click</button><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>
    <div class="count"><span>3</span><button class="click">Click</button><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>
    <div class="count"><span>4</span><button class="click">Click</button><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <div class="count"><span>2</span><button class="click">Click</button><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>
    <div class="count"><span>3</span><button class="click">Click</button><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>
    <div class="count"><span>4</span><button class="click">Click</button><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for my poor sample, the simplified html markup is just a sample to explain my situation. It is in fact a <span> inside .count. But I can't get your snippet to work. It just removes the element without updating the count

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen  Snippet updated in order to handle spans